# Unity import package is not importing correct version

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm trying to import  `Mirror` package (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/mirror-129321) but it doesn't seems to import latest version.

The version specified in Package manager is "30.2.2": [image]

But what I have in the `version.txt` of is "11.4.2":
[image]

I already tried to delete and reimport the folder. I also tried a `Reimport` but without success.

Is their some sort of cache ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing directly in local Asset Store directory and redownload it from the online Asset Store.

1. Go to `C:\Users\<YourUser>\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x\` and delete the package you want to redownload.
2. Once the package is deleted, go in https://assetstore.unity.com/account/assets and click the blue button "Open in Unity". Once open in Unity, click the "download" button.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried getting it from the package manager and I got the right version (30.2.2). Note that the version.txt file is just a text file and mine shows 30.2.1 even though I got 30.2.2.

All the packages are cached under the "Library" folder. You can try closing Unity, deleting the Library folder and opening your project again. Unity will re-download all the packages at that point.

To remove the package from your project you can either:

1. Find the package in package manager window within Unity and press the "remove" button. Unity should instantly remove the package from the cache folder instantly.
2. Remove it from the Packages/manifest.json file. Close Unity first if going this route. Unity will sync the cache with the manifest.json the next time you open the project.

Comment: I tried deleting the Library folder but it still importing version 11.4.2. Is their any way to completely remove the package from "myAssets" and restart the download from the asset store as it was the first time ?

Comment: edited my reply to include how to remove the package from project. At that point it should be the same as never having add the package to the project. MyAssets is a asset store term and you can do that from the website or the asset store window.

Comment: Thank you for those precisions. It can be useful for others but in my case it didn't solve the issue.